# Partitions for installing Ubuntu beside windows

Tags: partitioning

I know that for installing Ubuntu we need a boot drive ( / ) and home ( /home ) and ( /swap )

but I don't know what is swap and home

Now if I install Ubuntu beside windows without any home and swap drive is it okay ? can I work correctly with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/home` is a separate partition for your personal data, in case you have to reinstall Ubuntu you won't lose it.

`swap` is a partition which is **somehow** the equivalent of `pagefile.sys` in Windows. It is used when you run out of RAM.

To install Ubuntu you need `/` partition and `/swap`. `/home` is optional but recommended.

So, in Windows right click `Computer`, then `Manage` and select `Disk management`. Delete or shrink the last partition and leave a minimum of 15 GB unallocated space (for a decent install).

After that boot from an Ubuntu DVD/USB and when greeted with the partitioning options select `Something Else`. Click the `Unallocated space` and press `New` button. Select `at the end` and use as `swap`. Let it be as much or a little more than your RAM.

Now click again the unallocated space and press `New` button and create an `ext4` partition mounted as `/`.

If you want `/home` partition then leave some space from it and create it by choosing mount point `/home` and `ext4` type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare partition you want to install ubuntu onto then do an automatic install where Ubuntu will setup all the partitions it needs for you using the one you gave it alongside your Windows install...

/home is where programs store local data and settings and your own files separate from the ubuntu filesystem itself...

/swap is the partition it uses as extra memory when your computer runs out of actual hardware memory, it's a lot slower since it's using the hard-drive...

Answer (score 0):

`/swap` isn't really necessary if you've RAM more than 2GB. Its used by Ubuntu in case it runs out of (RAM) memory.

`/home` is similar to the `C:\Users` directory in Windows where the files and settings of every individual users are stored. You do not need to create a separate partition for home if you don't wish to. Ubuntu should be able to create a `/home` directory in the same partition as `/`.

Comment: I have 4GB ram and I dont need to use /home so Can I just use install beside the windows ?

Comment: Yes, you can just install it besides Windows. You can put all your linux directories in a single partition. Just make sure you do not touch your Windows partition at all during the partitioning and the installation.